# C# Access DB Update Query doesnt execute though it acts like it did

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I can't for the life of me get this update query to work.

The Message Box pops up and says it has updated but then when I look, it didn't! This is an example of what the data looks like in these three fields:

```
Syslink = {EF45612D-6321-4D19-97A5-C9497D60D628}
CMCID = 44061
SEC_ID = {00EADB9A-6158-4D2B-85E4-E381CCB02611}
```

The columns are ordered as such: SEC_ID, SYSLINK, CMCID.
In the design view in access, all three of these fields are "Number" data types though from what I've seen across StackOverflow is that this doesn't matter when using AddWithValue unless I'm misunderstanding that.

```
private void buttonMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bredConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = bredConn;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Component_Section SET [SEC_SYS_COMP_ID]='@Syslink',[SEC_CMC_LINK]='@Cmcid' WHERE [SEC_ID]='@Secid'";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Syslink", labelDebugDestinationSYSLink.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cmcid", labelDebugDestinationCMC.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Secid", labelDebugSourceSECID.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        bredConn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Moved", "It moved", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error: On Move", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        bredConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters you dont need ticks around parameters.  Change `'@Syslink'` to `@Syslink` etc.  Then be sure you are writing to the same DB that you are viewing to see if it "moved".   Number seems incorrect type for Syslink  and SEC_ID

Comment: I've done it without the ticks and with the ticks but it still won't update. The "Number" type can't be changed and is default by the client.

Comment: I did say 'for starters' - you have other problems.  `OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` is a function which returns the number of rows affected.  If it is non zero, it *did* change something and you have to go back and make sure you are looking at the right DB copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I always avoid using `AddWithValue` for a [large number of reasons](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) I won't go in depth.

I see two obvious issues with the code so far.

1. The `OleDbParameter` type for each parameter is being inferred because of `AddWithValue`.  Use `Add` instead and be sure to specify the correct type matching the database type.
2. Using single quotes around parameters in your query string such as `'@Syslink'`.  This is unnecessary at best (`OleDbParameter` handles this automatically) and breaking at worst as it's used primarily for string comparison.

Making these changes gives the added benefit that your `Text` fields can convert to the correct type.

Regarding your current behavior, the query is running (otherwise an exception would be thrown) but the `WHERE` filter is failing to match the row you expect it to.

Make the above changes and try again.

Comment: Im still getting the same result. Message box shows up but nothing actually changed. 

Tried it doing this:
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Component_Section SET [SEC_SYS_COMP_ID]=@Syslink, [SEC_CMC_LINK]=@Cmcid WHERE [SEC_ID]=@Secid";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Syslink", OleDbType.VarChar, 60).Value = labelDebugDestinationSYSLink.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cmcid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(labelDebugDestinationCMC.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Secid", OleDbType.VarChar, 60).Value = labelDebugSourceSECID.Text;

Comment: @kdotcannon `VarChar`?  Still a string comparison.  What's the type of `SEC_ID` in the database?  It might be easiest to update your question with a manual command that _does_ work through the designer.  I could make some inferences from that.  It does not look like they are actually `Number` data types.

Comment: Ah fixed it - these are guids not Varchar. Its working correctly now. Thank you for the help.